# How to get iCloud user info in OSX sdk?

Tags: objective-c, macos, icloud, icloud-api

> How to get iCloud user info such as **login email** or **user name**
>   in OSX ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no API to access iCloud account details.

If you use the AddressBook framework, you could try looking up the "me" card in `ABAddressBook`. That might include the person's iCloud email, but it might not. You really have no reliable way to get this information without the user's permission, so why not just ask them?